# how do i set sublime to comment out every single line when selecting a block (html)?

Tags: html, sublimetext3

my Sublime Text 3 toggles comments in a very weird way when i select multiple lines

because there are already one-liner comments in the selected block i have to toggle the comment on every single line to make sure it doesnt break,

how can i change sublime to comment out every line with

```
<!-- line1 -->
<!-- <!-- line2 --> -->
<!-- line3 -->
```

instead of

```
<!-- line1 
<!-- line2 -->
line3
-->
```

?

sublime text 3 with html markup view and only emmet as plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible because when you select a code block it just appends the comment start and end tags to the code depending upon the type of language.
There is nothing specified in the preferences about this.